# stuck with python project

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project of my own, and I'm at a point where i don't know anymore what to do..

I'm trying to implement some sounds into my project where i press some tact. switches and they should make sounds.. I'm a complete newbie with python so i found a piece of code doing something similar...

```
import os
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q binary-language-moisture-evaporators.mp3 &')
    if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q power-converters.mp3 &')
    if (GPIO.input(25)== False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q vader.mp3 &')
    sleep(0.1);
```

I want the 1st sound to run in a continuous loop while `input(23)==false` and if one of the other two buttons is pressed it stops the first one and plays the other, only once, and returns to checking if `input(23)==false`

I need this to be done to finish my project, but I don't have the need really to learn python from scratch (at least for now). at least some guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Three switches give 8 possible input states.  It it not clear from your description what you want to have happen for each combination of inputs.  Start by making a chart that makes this clear.  It will then be possible to revise the `if` statements to match.

Comment: the switches are independent... 1 switch should do 1 sound... one has to be in a loop while the button is pressed, until i hit one of the other two buttons, then it should stop all other sounds and play the sound corresponding to the button pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This codes seems working (as I simulated it). You may need modify it to suite your need though. For example, if both 24 and 25 are pressed, which one should be played (24 takes precedence over 25 in the code).

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN) 

proc1 = ''
proc2 = ''
proc3 = ''
while True:
    if GPIO.input(24) == False:
        if proc3:
            proc3.kill()
            proc3 = ''
        if proc2 and proc2.poll() is None:
            proc2.kill()
            proc2 = ''
        if not proc1 or proc1.poll() is not None:
            proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['mpg123','-q','power-converters.mp3'])
    elif GPIO.input(25) == False:
        if proc3:
            proc3.kill()
            proc3 = ''
        if proc1 and proc1.poll() is None:
            proc1.kill()
            proc1 = ''
        if not proc2 or proc2.poll() is not None:
            proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['mpg123','-q','vader.mp3'])
    elif GPIO.input(23) == False:
        if not (proc1 and proc1.poll() is None) and not (proc2 and proc2.poll() is None):
            if not proc3 or proc3.poll() is not None:
                proc3 = subprocess.Popen(['mpg123','-q','binary-language-moisture-evaporators.mp3'])
    elif proc3 and proc3.poll() is None:
        proc3.kill()
        proc3 = ''

    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: while testing it, you may insert a print statement below each if statement to make sure it can detect the pressed button.

Comment: and you also need to decide, if 25 is pressed while 24 is still playing, whether to kill 24 or let it play to finish (the code lets it finish).

Comment: yes!! that is exactly it. since the 24 and 25 are like drum hits (short) it isn't important whether one finishes before the other starts. thank you so much "Shiping". seeing your code now makes this programming language much more familiar and much more understandable for me.... my project (which is a game for my two nephews to have something to hammer on) will now have the nice professional touch thanks to you... thank you again so much

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
play = True
while True:

    if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        play = False
        os.system('mpg123 -q power-converters.mp3 &')
    else:
        play = True

    if (GPIO.input(25)== False):
        play = False
        os.system('mpg123 -q vader.mp3 &')
    else:
        play = True

    if (play and GPIO.input(23) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -q binary-language-moisture-evaporators.mp3 &')

    sleep(0.1);
```

Comment: but if all sounds are long, it may not work as desired.

Comment: the sounds are up to 5secs long, thanks, this looks, to my c++ eyes, much clearer, but still does the same thing :S

Comment: then the code won't stop what's already in play. you need to kill mpg123 if 25 or 23 is pressed to stop the sound immediately.

Comment: should i add an if statement in the existing ones (for the two that should break the loop sound), any link on a nice tutorial on the syntax for kill.. i tried some kill function combinations, but i can find any clear instructions on how to write them properly

Comment: once 23 or 25 is pressed, do you want it's sound to play to the finish before start 24?

Comment: yes.. the sound 24 recording has a delay, so it can go as soon as tha23 or 25 ends

Comment: you may look into subprocess, do something like proc = subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', '-q', 'binary-language-moisture-evaporators.mp3']), then do proc.kill() when 24 or 25 is pressed. but you also need to check if 24 or 25 is still in play when 23 is pressed.

Comment: tried that as well. no results really, j thought solutions would be easier, with loops or something like that, thanks for trying to help me.. im hopeless